# What’s the best way to Convert a list to dict in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a list like:

```
x = ['user=inci', 'password=1234', 'age=12', 'number=33']
```

I want to convert x to a dict like:

```
{'user': 'inci', 'password': 1234, 'age': 12, 'number': 33}
```

what's the quickest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple one liner:

```
dict(item.split('=') for item in x)
```

List comprehensions (or generator expressions) are generally faster than using `map` with `lambda` and are normally considered more readable, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).

Answer (score 2):

### Benchmark

**`dict` and `map` approach (`f1`)**

```
dict(map(lambda i: i.split('='), x))
```

**Naive approach (`f2`)**

```
d = dict()
for i in x:
    s = x.split("=")
    d[s[0]] = s[1]
return d
```

**Only `dict` (`f3`)**

```
dict(item.split('=') for item in x)
```

---

**Comparison**

```
def measure(f, x):
    t0 = time()
    f(x)
    return time() - t0

>>> x = ["{}={}".format(i, i) for i in range(1000000)]

>>> measure(f1, x)
0.5690059661865234

>>> measure(f2, x)
0.5518567562103271

>>> measure(f3, x)
0.5470657348632812
```

Comment: when the  length of list is very big, the Naive approach is quicker. However , the  "dict(item.split('=') for item in x)" method is quicker than Naive approach  when the length of list is small.

Comment: @nanci Actually, that last approach (that you accepted) remains better when the list is huge.

Answer (score 1):

`dict(map(lambda i: i.split('='), x))`

Comment: This method is slower than dict(item.split('=') for item in x)